# In a LINQ with a select can I compare forward to the next row and decide what to select?

Tags: c#, linq

What I implemented with a for loop is this:

```
            phraseSources2 = new List<PhraseSource2>();
            for (int i = 0; i < phraseSources.Count; i++)
            {
                var ps = phraseSources[i];
                if (i != phraseSources.Count - 1)
                {
                    var psNext = phraseSources[i + 1];
                    if (psNext != null &&
                        ps.Kanji == psNext.Kanji &&
                        ps.Kana == psNext.Kana &&
                        ps.English.Length <= psNext.English.Length)
                    {
                        i++;
                        ps = phraseSources[i];
                    }
                } else
                {
                    ps = phraseSources[i];
                }
                phraseSources2.Add(new PhraseSource2()
                {
                    Kanji = ps.Kanji,
                    Kana = ps.Kana,
                    Furigana = ps.Furigana,
                    English = ps.English,
                });
            }
```

Previously I had been using LINQ

```
            phraseSources2 = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources
            .Select(x => new PhraseSource2()
            {
                Kanji = x.Kanji,
                Kana = x.Kana,
                Furigana = x.Furigana,
                English = x.English,
            }).ToList();
```

I know LINQ can do a lot but can it look forward at the next row when doing a select?

Comment: Did you mean `var psNext = phraseSources[i+1];`?

Comment: If I understand your problem correcly I wouldn't "look forward" but use `GroupBy` instead and group by `Kanji` and `Kana` then select the longest `English` as the new `PhraseSource2` object.

Comment: That code seems wrong because of `ps` and `psNext` being set to the same thing initially.  Also it's going to cause an index out of range exception when increment `i` in that `if` without checking if it's gone beyond the end of the array/list.  Also `phraseSource2` is `null` so there's a null reference exception as well.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen - Thanks for pointing out that error of mine.

Comment: @juharr - Thanks for pointing out that it would be a problem when it goes beyond the size of the list.

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lag - `Lag` or `Lead`. Note - this assumes your source is `IEnumerable` rather than `IQueryable` based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correcly I wouldn't "look forward" but use `GroupBy` instead and group by `Kanji` and `Kana` then `Select` the longest `English` as the value in the  `PhraseSource2` object.

Something like this:

```
var phraseSource2 = phraseSources
    .GroupBy(x => new {Kanji = x.Kanji, Kana = x.Kana})
    .Select(g => new PhraseSource2 {
        Kanji = g.Key.Kanji,
        Kana = g.Key.Kana,
        Furigana = g.First().Furigana,
        English = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.English.Length).First().English
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the source collection can be accessed by index than you can use an overload to the select which gives you the current index.

```
var source = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var result = source.Select((x, i) => new { Current = x, Next = source.Length > i+1 ? source[i+1] : ' '});
```

Comment: Yes the  source collection can be accessed by an index but in the case of this question, how could I do the compare of multiple properties like I am doing. Could that also be done?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is just set up a variable inside a query where you can easily retrieve next or previous value like this:

```
 phraseSources2 = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources
            .Select((x, y) =>
                var NextKanji = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources.Skip(y + 1).FirstOrDefault().Kanji;

                new PhraseSource2()
            {
                Kanji = NextKanji,
                Kana = x.Kana,
                Furigana = x.Furigana,
                English = x.English,
            }).ToList();
```

If you want to check some conditions before, you can do it like this:

```
phraseSources2 = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources
            .Where((x, y) =>
                var NextEnglish = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources.Skip(y + 1).FirstOrDefault().English;
                x.English.Length < NextEnglish.Length)
            .Select(x =>
                new PhraseSource2()
            {
                Kanji = x.Kanji,
                Kana = x.Kana,
                Furigana = x.Furigana,
                English = x.English,
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but how could I implement this to check something more complicated like I'm doing where I check if two things are the same and then if the length of the English property is smaller. Can I just sort the list by Kanji, Kana and English (length) and then pick the last item with some sort of order by?

Comment: I have added second approach by using indexes in my answer. Might this be something you need?

Comment: Thanks, I am checking that now. How about the check that I implement where I check the length of the English property and just use the one list item with the longest?

Comment: This is the check I'm doing: ps.English.Length <= psNext.English.Length

Comment: You can just check it on Where before doing Select.

Comment: Hi, I think it's close to being what I need but I get errors here: Kanji NextEnglish = (List<Data1.Model.PhraseSource2>)phraseSources.Skip(y + 1).FirstOrDefault().English;
                x.English.Length < NextEnglish.Length)

Comment: Replace first Kanji with var, my bad

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method, but there are third-party libraries that offer this functionality. The [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) is a respected and free .NET library that offers a [`WindowLeft`](http://morelinq.github.io/3.2/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Window__1.htm) extension method, that processes a sequence into a series of subsequences representing a windowed subset of the original. So you could use it to process your phraseSources in pairs, and discard the pairs that have two equal phrases. Finally select the first phrase of the pairs that survived.

```
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.WindowLeftExtension;

var phraseSources2 = phraseSources
.WindowLeft(size: 2)
.Where(phrases => // phrases is of type IList<PhraseSource2>
{
    if (phrases.Count == 2) // All have size 2 except from the last
    {
        var ps = phrases[0];
        var psNext = phrases[1];
        return ps.Kanji != psNext.Kanji || ps.Kana != psNext.Kana ||
            ps.English.Length > psNext.English.Length;
    }
    else // The last is a single phrase
    {
        return true;
    }
})
.Select(window => window[0]) // Select the first phrase
.ToList();
```